# Sobolev regularity via Laplace spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, eigenvalues, laplacian

Fix a positive integer $n$ and let $\mu$ be the uniform measure on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$, with respect to its usual Riemannian metric $g$. Let $\nabla$ be the Laplacian on $(\mathbb{S}^n,g)$ and suppose that $f\in L^2_{\mu}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ has eigendecomposition $(\lambda_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying
$$
\lambda_n \asymp n^{-r}
$$
for some $r>0$,
where $\lambda_n:=\langle f,\psi_n\rangle$ where $(\psi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are the eigenfunctions of $\nabla$ therein.

Under what conditions, if any, on the "rate" $r$ can we infer that $f\in H^{k}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ for some $k$ and bound its Sobolev norm $\|f\|_{H^k}$ as a function of $(\lambda_n)_n$?

Furthermore, (when) can we get a bound on its Lipschitz constant using this data?

Comment: I guess you would look at the $H^k$ norms of the eigenfunctions and see if they grow more slowly than $n^r$.  Probably this rate is known.  Similar for the Lipschitz constants, using $W^{1, \infty}$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can be nearly-completely resolved. Namely, as in Stein-Weiss' book on Fourier analysis on Euclidean spaces, there is a *sharp* bound on the ratio of sup-norm to $L^2$-norm of spherical harmonics of a given degree. In fact, the result admits considerable abstraction...!  That ratio is (up to a constant depending on measure, which obviously affects $L^2$ norm but not sup-norm) something like the square root of the dimension of the corresponding irreducible repn of the orthogonal group.

(This replaces the all-too-happy estimate $|e^{i\xi x}|\le 1$ in the tiniest case.)

Some simple algebra (!) shows that the dimensions grow polynomially (in an explicit way...).

So, yes, ignoring details to give a qualitative answer, there is indeed a very explicit good Sobolev theory on spheres. My notes [https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/09_spheres.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/09_spheres.pdf) do lots of background, and write out the case of sufficiently high Sobolev index implies continuity, as an example.

Addition after OP's comment/question: here, as in other cases where we have a Laplacian eigenfunction expansion, with sufficient info about the eigenfunctions and growth rate of their eigenvalues... an "expression" $f=\sum_n \langle f,u_n\rangle\cdot u_n$ for a "function" $f$ in terms of an orthonormal basis $\{u_n\}$ for $L^2$ consisting of eigenfunctions for the Laplacian immediately gives all the $H^k$ norms, even for general $k\in\mathbb R$.

Namely, first, for the definition $|f|^2_{H^k}=\langle (1-\Delta)^kf,f\rangle$ with $0\le k\in\mathbb Z$,
$$
|f|^2_{H^k} \;=\; \sum_n |\langle f,u_n\rangle|^2\cdot \langle (1-\Delta)^k u_n,u_n\rangle
\;=\;
\sum_n |\langle f,u_n\rangle|^2\cdot (1-\lambda_n)^k
$$
where I've changed notation so that $\Delta u_n=\lambda_n$.

Second, in fact the right-hand side of the latter display makes perfect sense for $k$ an arbitrary real number.

Comment: Ah very interesting!  Just one thing, this only gives a sup-bound and not a bound on the Sobolev norms ($H^k$ or $W^{1,\infty}$) (does it?)

Comment: Also is the inner product in $L^2$ or in $H^k$?

Comment: The unlabelled angle brackets are meant to be in $L^2$...

Comment: what book should i look up to read more/cite this type of thing?

Comment: (I could not find it in the basic Fourier analysis books I found in the library)

Comment: Right, this will not be in basic Fourier analysis books. My own course notes in Real Analysis cover this kind of thing carefully for ordinary Fourier series. Some of my modular forms notes do treat the spherical harmonics case analogously. Once one gets the idea, it's not hard to do the Hilbert space case generally. G. Folland's Tata lectures on PDE start with the analogue for Fourier transforms on $\mathbb R^n$, and that was where I got the idea... :)

Comment: Oh really?  Ok cool then I have some reading in my near future; Thanks Paul :)